# Is there any way to simplify this expression so that a term only appears once?

Tags: notation

I have an expression:
$$ \frac{x+z}{y+z} $$

Can I reorganize it so that any variable only appears once?

Comment: $\frac{x+z}{y+z}=1+\frac{x-y}{y+z}$

Comment: $\dfrac{x+z}{y+z}=\dfrac{x-y+y+z}{y+z}=1+\dfrac{x-y}{y+z}$

Comment: Sorry, forgot one thing. See my edit.

Comment: Let $w=x+z$, then you have $w\over y+z$.

Comment: Without using any new variable names.

Comment: NO, (sorry i need to add some more text)